# Same, but different questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

**How are nearly identical questions supposed to be handled on NE/SE?** Are they always to be treated separately with votes and rewards or is there a mechanism have moderators or more privileged users indicate it's a duplicate questions; therefore, should have a duplicate answer.

These are examples of potentially duplicate questions, though it could be argued these particular ones should not be considered dupes.  This just raised the question (no pun intended) for me on how dupes would be handled *if* they could be determined to be such.

[Setting up DHCP server on the router or on the switch?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/setting-up-dhcp-server-on-the-router-or-on-the-switch)

[Where to properly put the DHCP server?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1699/where-to-properly-put-the-dhcp-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vote to close such questions and select the 'duplicate' option when voting to close. It gives you an input field where you can paste the URL to the other question.